# Run a sqlcmd in a batch process with a For /f loop

Tags: parsing, for-loop, batch-processing, sqlcmd

I'm trying to use a For loop in a batch process to execute a sqlcmd multiple times.  The For loop is supposed to parse through a txt file where each line is the name of a Study in a database.  The sqlcmd query is supposed to pull the appropriate data and populate a csv file with the name of the study.  The sqlcmd works by itself making a single csv if I declare the variable internally.  The batch process works in that it parses through text file and makes a csv for each study in it but it doesn't populate the files.  Here is the sqlcmd query...

```
DECLARE @StudyName nvarchar(255)
SET @StudyName='$(StudyName)'

DECLARE @TblTVM TABLE(StudyId int, Animal nvarchar(100), DATE varchar(100), LL float, LWi float, LTVM float)


INSERT INTO @TblTVM (StudyId, Animal, DATE, LL,LWi, LTVM)
    SELECT
        S.StudyId,
        A.PermanentId AS 'Animal',
        (CAST(Datepart(Month, V.PerformDateTime) AS varchar(2))) + '/' + (CAST(Datepart(Day, V.PerformDateTime) AS varchar(2))) + '/' + (CAST(Datepart(Year, V.PerformDateTime) AS varchar(4))) AS 'DATE',
        V.Length AS 'LL',
        V.Width AS 'LWi',
        V.Volume AS 'LTVM'
FROM TblStudy S
    INNER JOIN tblAnimals A ON S.StudyId = A.StudyID
    INNER JOIN TblTumorVolume V ON A.AnimalId = V.AnimalId
    INNER JOIN TblImplants I ON V.ImplantId = I.ImplantID
WHERE
    S.StudyNumber LIKE @StudyName AND
    I.ImplSite LIKE N'Left';


SELECT
    L.Animal,
    L.DATE,
    LL,
    LWi,
    LTVM

FROM @TblTVM L
ORDER BY
2,
1
```

And here is the .bat file...

```
@echo off

set /p dir="What file?"

FOR /f %%X in (%dir%) do (
    SET "StudyName=%%X"
    SQLCMD -d StudyLog_Summary -i C:\Tools\2CSVQuery.sql -o C:\Tools\CSVs\%%X.csv -W -s","
)
```

Any help in figuring my the csv files are empty (ie. 0 lines completed)  would be great.

Thanks,
Jeff